# db2 migration and upgrade Error

Tags: database, db2, migration

I Migrated  db2 database mydb2 from V9.7 to V10.5

I am getting the following error while trying to upgrade db2 
[db2inst1@server22 tmp]$ db2 UPGRADE DATABASE mydb2 user db2inst1 using db2inst1
SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "ADMIN_GET_TEMP_TABLES" of type 
"FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.  SQLSTATE=42884

Any Suggestions.?

Comment: What is the fix pack level of the 9.7 database? Was it previously migrated from an earlier DB2 version? You may want to install the latest 9.7 fix pack and perform _all_ post-installation tasks, including running `db2updv97`

Comment: Yes it was Migrated from 9.5 fixpack 5 ..The fixpack in 9.7 is version 3

Comment: The latest [DB2 9.7 fix pack](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27007053) is 9